# Problem on writing long equation

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment

The following example code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  mathrm{salary} &= mathrm{Intercept} + mathrm{academicYear}*(-154.68)+mathrm{tuitionOfferPerMonth}*166.42 +\\
  & mathrm{tutionsYouHaveDone}*88.12 + mathrm{result} *2174.74 +mathrm{teachingHour}*762.86+\\
  & mathrm{subjectsYouTaught}*(-99.42) +  mathrm{daysInWeek}*(-471.26)+mathrm{tuitionType}*469.36 + mathrm{studentClass}* 159.81 + mathrm{Dept.science} *1902.81 + mathrm{Hall} *(-1057.61) 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

generates this error message:

```
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
l.5   mathrm{salary} &
                      = mathrm{Intercept} + mathrm{academicYear}*(-154.68)+m...

?
```

Now, what can I do so that the equation aligned with the `=` sign?

Comment: the `&` mark the alignment point so you want `&=`  in the first row, but put `\mathrm{..]` around each word first

Comment: You need to place an `aligned` environment inside the `equation` environment in block 6. Also, it should be `\mathrm` rather than just `mathrm`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have a multi-line equation, you need to use a `split` or `aligned` inner environment. Also, you need to supply one more line break to make the material fit. And, in fine math typography, do use `\cdot` instead of `*` to indicate multiplication.

Better still, rearrange the terms so that the coefficients come *before*, rather than after, the coefficients. That way, the `\cdot` terms can be dispensed with entirely, and you end up with a much more compact (and, arguably, more readable) equation, as the second equation in the following screenshot demonstrates.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry} % set the page size parameters appropriately
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{salary} 
&=\text{Intercept} + \text{academicYear}\cdot(-154.68)+\text{tuitionOfferPerMonth}\cdot166.42 \\
&\quad+ \text{tuitionsYouHaveDone}\cdot88.12 + \text{result} \cdot2174.74 +\text{teachingHour}\cdot762.86\\
&\quad+ \text{subjectsYouTaught}\cdot(-99.42) + \text{daysInWeek}\cdot(-471.26)+\text{tuitionType}\cdot469.36\\
&\quad+ \text{studentClass}\cdot 159.81 + \text{Dept.science} \cdot1902.81 + \text{Hall} \cdot(-1057.61) 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{salary} 
&=\text{Intercept} -154.68\,\text{academicYear}+166.42\,\text{tuitionOfferPerMonth} \\
&\quad+ 88.12\,\text{tuitionsYouHaveDone} + 2174.74\,\text{result} +762.86\,\text{teachingHour}\\
&\quad-99.42\,\text{subjectsYouTaught} -471.26\,\text{daysInWeek}+469.36\,\text{tuitionType}\\
&\quad+ 159.81\,\text{studentClass}  + 1902.81\,\text{Dept.science} -1057.61\,\text{Hall}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Re “fine math typography” … there is nothing wrong with `*` in fine math typography, but its meaning is *convolution*, not multiplication.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen - You agree, then, with what I wrote -- "use `\cdot` instead of `*` to indicate multiplication" -- right? Or are you contemplating the possibility that the OP really meant to indicate convolution, and I just happen to have missed it completely? :-)

Comment: No, I agree with you there. But I think it has more to do with the *meaning* of the symbols than the *fineness* (if that is the word) of the typesetting. Using `*` for multiplication is for programming languages, and should never happen elsewhere. Even in crappy math typography. :-)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen - I've edited my answer to show how the equation looks like if the ordering of the coefficients and variable names is reversed, allowing the removal of all `\cdot` directives.

Comment: That's quite nice.

Comment: @Mico why don't you use `\times`?

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \alignLongstack{
  \text{Salary} =& \text{Intercept} &{}+\\& \text{Academic Year}&\times(-154.68)+
  \\& \text{Tuition Offer Per Month}&\times166.42 +
  \\& \text{Tuitions You Have Done}&\times88.12 +\\& \text{Result} &\times2174.74 +
  \\& \text{Teaching Hour}&\times762.86 +\\& \text{Subjects You Taught} &\times(-99.42) +
  \\& \text{Days In Week}&\times(-471.26) +\\& \text{Tuition Type}&\times469.36 +
  \\& \text{Student Class}&\times 159.81 +\\& \text{Dept. Science} &\times1902.81 +
  \\& \text{Hall} &\times(-1057.61)\phantom{{}+{}}
  }
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the equation number centered, change `\alignLongstack` to `\alignCenterstack`.

Comment: Your decoration is good, but having probability to confuse whether it is equation or anything else. Would you provide another decoration alongside with this. I believe you can. Don't upset, I upvote your answer.

Comment: @alhelal I am not sure I understand what you mean by another "decoration".

Comment: You're not sure what "another [math] decoration" is? :-)

Comment: @Mico Not in this context I am not.  Am I being asked to change `times` to `\cdot` for example?  I can't tell.

Comment: Don't feel too bad -- I don't know either what a math decoration is supposed to be. I suspect that, just maybe, the OP was using editing software that blithely auto-corrected "equation" to "decoration"...